# How to retrieve a constant value by providing a string?

Tags: java

Considering this class

```
package com.bluegrass.core;

public class Constants {
    public static final String AUTHOR="bossman";
    public static final String COMPANY="Bluegrass";
    //and many more constants below
}
```

I want to create a function that goes like this:

```
getConstantValue("AUTHOR") //this would return "bossman"
```

Any ideas how this can be done?

Comment: Why do you think you need this?

Comment: an enum will work for you.

Comment: This is likely an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). Please elaborate on what your actual requirement is.

Comment: or use a `Map` instead

Comment: Based on the little bit of code you posted I _think_ a `Map<>` is what you want, not an `enum`, but without more context on what you're actually going to do with this it is not possible to tell.  You already have several answers written by people who have tried to guess your intentions, but until you clarify the question I would be hesitant to choose one answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use reflection:

```
public static String getConstantValue(String name) {
    try {
        return (String) Constants.class.getDeclaredField(name).get(null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Constant value not found: " + name, e);
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE:** Enum solution.

If you can change the `Constants` class to be an `enum`, it would be like this instead:

```
private static String getConstantValue(String name) {
    return Constants.valueOf(name).getText();
}
```

But that requires something like this for `Constants`:

```
public enum Constants {
    AUTHOR("bossman"),
    COMPANY("Bluegrass");

    private final String text;

    private Constants(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
    public String getText() {
        return this.text;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Hawk How is that an overkill? The code stays exactly the same, even if there are 100+ constants. Without knowing exactly how many, and the comment *"and many more constants below"* in the question code suggests it to be "a lot", this is the simplest *scalable* implementation of `getConstantValue`.

Comment: i think simplest solution is to use enum

Comment: @SungJinSteveYoo It requires less code inside `getConstantValue`, but more code inside `Constants`, and it requires that `Constants` can be changed, which is not necessarily possible. Overall, I wouldn't say that it is any simpler. Added `enum` solution to answer so you can compare them for yourself.

Comment: or maybe just use a properties file

Comment: @ScaryWombat I like that one.

Comment: @SungJinSteveYoo True. I would never say that having to change every single line of `Constants` is a simple solution, which is why I disagree with your statement that `enum` is simplest solution. Guess it depends on your starting point.

Comment: The first option is just perfectly brilliant to query constant values from Android classes via Cordova plugin, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest solution (and also work with enums instead of String is typesafe) is to work with enum, provided you are able to change the `public static final` fields into an enum.

```
public enum Constants {
    AUTHOR("bossman"),
    COMPANY("Bluegrass");

    private final String content;

    Constants (String content) {
        this.content= content;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public static Constants getConstant(String content) {
        for (Constants constant : Constants.values()) {
            if (constant.getContent().equals(content)) {
                return constant;
            }
        }
        return null; //default value
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
Constants.valueOf("AUTHOR") == Constants.AUTHOR
Constants.getConstant("bossman") == Constants.AUTHOR
Constants.AUTHOR.getContent() == "bossman"
```

So instead of OP's `getConstantValue("AUTHOR")` it would be `Constants.valueOf("AUTHOR").getContent()`

Comment: That won't work. Did you intend for caller to do `Constants.getConstant("AUTHOR")` and get `"bossman"` back? Won't happen, firstly because that wouldn't compile, and even if it did, it would return `null`.

Comment: `getConstant()` implementation also can be replaced with `Enum.valueOf()` with try-catch

Comment: @SungJinSteveYoo Why would you use `Enum.valueOf(Constants.class, name)` when `Constants.valueOf(name)` is available, and *simpler* to use?

Comment: @Andreas Sorry for that. Didn't meant to use real `Enum`'s method. My thought was using `EnumClassName.valueOf`

Comment: @Andreas no, it works like `getConstant("bossman")==Constants.AUTHOR` and it most certainly compiles. Don't need a utility method if you have `Constants.valueOf()`, now do you?

Comment: Please **read the question**. OP want a method `getConstantValue("AUTHOR")` that returns `"bossman"`. Method must take a `String` with the *name* of the constant, and return a `String` with the *value* of the constant. Sure, you can rename the method if you want *(but why?)*, but changing the method to map the other way is definitely *not* a useful answer.

Comment: @Andreas I added usage example. You are maybe right, that it could be misleading, but I added this as a mean of transferring both ways which could be handy.

Comment: @Hawk None of those usage examples takes a `String` and returns a `String`, which is what question is asking for. To be useful, at least give what has been asked for, unless you *explain* why that's a bad idea, and show what should have been asked for instead, or you *explain* why your answer is a better idea, e.g. if question is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/351454).

Comment: @Andreas well I sincerely thought that the reader is intelligent enough to connect two consecutive lines as a simple mathematical equation

Answer (score 0):

There is a multitude of methods to solve this.

One way is to use a switch.

Example:

```
public String foo(String key) throws AnException {
  switch (key) {
    case case1:
      return constString1;
    case case2:
      return constString2;
    case case3:
      return constString3;
      ...
     default:
      throws NotValidKeyException; //or something along these lines
    }
}
```

The other method is to create a `map<string,string>` and fill it with the desired key,pairs.

Comment: Switch is raising the Cyclomatic complexity and also, you need to add another case manually to satisfy a new constant.

Map is not ideal, because you need to initialize it at runtime and it is a good practise to use compile-time everywhere you can.